# Scroll to top of div when it is not displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead, typeahead.js

I have a div full of typeahead search results.  When the input that the typeahead is bound to loses focus, I'd like the div that has the typeahead results to be scrolled to the top most position.

I'm using [typeahead.js](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js), so I currently have:

```
$('input[name="customer"]').on('typeahead:closed', function(){
    $('div.tt-dataset-customers').scrollTop(0);
});
```

The div is never scrolled, however.  Thinking that this was due to the div being hidden, I've also tried:

```
$('input[name="customer"]').on('typeahead:open', function(){
    $('div.tt-dataset-customers').scrollTop(0);
});
```

This did not work either.

Is there a way to set a scroll position on a div that isn't being shown?

Fiddle showing what's happening: http://jsfiddle.net/tTdF4/

Comment: It's a bit of a hack but you could try sizing the div to 1px height and changing the opacity to 0

Comment: I don't want to hide an already hidden div, I want to set the scroll position.

Comment: Technically, you are un-hiding with my suggestion

Comment: The problem with that is that typeahead.js doesn't fire an event when the suggestions are rendered.  So I don't have an event I can listen to to watch for the div full of suggestions to become visible.  It does have the "closed" event, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit v3**

So I've added a `console.log` on this and it never fired.

```
$('input[name="customer"]').on('typeahead:closed', function(){
    console.log('test');
});
```

So instead of splitting `typeahead()` from `on()`, I've used jQuery chain and now it is  triggering `typeahead:closed`. Don't ask me why it wasn't triggering, still didn't figured out :(.

Anyways, this will work (tested on chrome v29) when you type `a`, scroll down, click outside then click back on the input, the list will be back up.

```
$('input[name="customers"]').typeahead({
    local: ['a','ab','ac','ad','ae','af',
            'ag','ah','ai','aj','ak','al',
            'am','an','ao','ap','aq','ar',
            'as','at','au','av','aw','ax',
            'ay','az'
    ],
    limit: 20,
    name: 'customers',
    rateLimitWait: 100,
    ttl: 300
}).on('typeahead:closed keypress', function(){
    console.log('test');
    $('div.tt-dataset-customers').animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, 900);
});
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tTdF4/1/)

p.s.: At least on fiddle, jquery 2.X and typeahead gives errors on both scritps on IE9 (see console), if you use `1.9 (edge)` then it will work.

V3: Added `keypress` to the listened events so it will try scroll up everytime someone type something (covers typing `a`, backspacing and typing `b` for e.g.).

Comment: Maybe this isn't clear enough in my question, but I want to set the scroll position within the div, not the whole window.

Comment: @tubaguy50035 Oh sorry. I was thinking about that now. The typeahead demo does not have scroll, you got a demo somewhere with scrolling results I could see? So I could test and edit the answer. But it's something like this.

Comment: That doesn't work.  Here is a fiddle that hopefully shows what the issue is: http://jsfiddle.net/tTdF4/

Comment: @tubaguy50035 Updated answer with your fiddle. Seems works if you use chaining instead of calling `on()` by itself.

Comment: @tubaguy50035 Glad to be of help =)

Comment: @tubaguy50035 No event of typeahead (`typeahead:opened typeahead:initialized typeahead:closed typeahead:selected typeahead:autocompleted`) triggers when just typing and backspacing, so I attached to the keypress too. http://jsfiddle.net/tTdF4/3/ Everytime you press a letter, it will try scroll up.